# Why it doesnt work when the user press enter ((keydown)) in javascript to close modal in this case?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

when the user press enter or escape key its supposed to close the modal but its work only with escape key why it doesnt work with enter key ?

here is the code below!

```
'use strict';

const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const btnsOpenModal = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');

const openModal = function () {
  modal.classList.remove('hidden');
  overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
};

const closeModal = function () {
  modal.classList.add('hidden');
  overlay.classList.add('hidden');
};

for (let btn of btnsOpenModal) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
}

// here is the code that work only with escape key but its supposed to work with enter key too !

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  console.log(event.key);
  if (!modal.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') closeModal();
    if (event.key === 'Enter') closeModal();
  }
});
```

this is html code below!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Modal window</title>
  </head>
  <body>      
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 1</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 2</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 3</button>

    <div class="modal hidden">
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
      <h1>I'm a modal window </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when the user press enter key its supposed to close the modal !

Comment: Not sure tbh, should work with key prop too, but try using `event.keyCode` instead like this for entery key `event.keyCode === 13`. What do you get in your console log? if even.key correctly logs "Enter" then something is wrong with your modal closing functionality and not with capturing keyboard event

Comment: Seems related to something else than this javascript snippet wich works fine.

Comment: @JSEvgeny `event.keyCode` is deprecated

Comment: @mbesson it doesn't matter much just for trying out as an alternative

Comment: and as @mbesson said your `addEventListener` works just fine, it must be something with closing logic

Comment: It also may depend on the content inside your modal, if you have a form there, then enter key acts as a trigger to submit the form, and if you then have `e.preventDefault` inside your form submission code, then your enter keypress ends there and is not "bubbled" to the parent, but I'm 100% sure about that, would need to check. But before that could you please verify that you don't have anything I mentioned in this comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is working snipper for you with a tiny adjustment to your code

This was actually suprising to me too, but I noticed that if you focus into the opened modal first (click into it) and then hit enter key, then everything works as expected. It seems that because Enter is sort of "specific" key that is usually doing form submissions (and might be something more) it seems like when some other element is focused while you press enter, the action targets currently focused element. Anyways, `event.preventDefault()` line is needed when "Enter" key is pressed to make things work as you expect.

```js
'use strict';

const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const btnsOpenModal = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');

const openModal = function () {
  modal.classList.remove('hidden');
  overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
};

const closeModal = function () {
  modal.classList.add('hidden');
  overlay.classList.add('hidden');
};

for (let btn of btnsOpenModal) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
}

// here is the code that work only with escape key but its supposed to work with enter key too !

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  console.log(event.key);
  if (!modal.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') closeModal();
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      closeModal();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Modal window</title>
  </head>
  <body>      
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 1</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 2</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 3</button>

    <div class="modal hidden">
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
      <h1>I'm a modal window </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because the button used to open the modal is still in focus and after you press `Enter` key the modal is closed but as the clicked button is still in focus that triggers the click event on button and your modal opens again. So, you can remove the focus on button after the modal has been open.

Here is a code snippet that should work.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
const btnsOpenModal = document.querySelectorAll(".show-modal");
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector(".close-modal");

const openModal = function () {
  modal.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
};

const closeModal = function () {
  modal.classList.add("hidden");
  overlay.classList.add("hidden");
};

const onOpenButtonClick = (e) => {
  openModal();
  // Here removing focus from button
  e.currentTarget.blur();
};

for (let btn of btnsOpenModal) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", onOpenButtonClick);
}

// here is the code that work only with escape key but its supposed to work with enter key too !

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  console.log(event.key);
  if (!modal.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    if (event.key === "Escape") closeModal();
    if (event.key === "Enter") closeModal();
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Modal window</title>
  </head>
  <body>      
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 1</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 2</button>
    <button class="show-modal">Show modal 3</button>

    <div class="modal hidden">
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
      <h1>I'm a modal window </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```